# How to make add to cart button to look like this image with css?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to edit add to cart button on product page for it to look like images below (That green button (it's actually just an image) same color, font size, black text outline and different size on desktop and mobile (responsive)). If it’s of any significant the size of “add to cart” button image (the green one) on mobile is full width (100%) while on desktop it’s around 56%. I figured out how to change color, button size (but looks terrible on mobile) with css but that's about it...

How add to cart button should look like on desktop (Like that green button):
[image: How add to cart button should look like on desktop (Like that green button)]

How it should look on mobile (green button, responsive full width):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the CSS of the current button.

Add this in your CSS:

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
background-image: url('http://veleran.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/AddToCartButton.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
width: 200px;
border: 0px; }
```

After that remove the text `Add to cart` in the current button and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try **writing this on your css** (at bottom ) adjust values if required

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.quantity+.button {
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 45px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 18px;
    line-height: 45px;
    min-height: 60px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #928282;
    background: #37ae33;
}
}
```

for example

```css
.button {
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 45px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 18px;
    line-height: 45px;
    /* height: 50px; */
    min-height: 60px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #928282;
    background: #37ae33;
text-align:center;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="button">Add To Cart</div>
```

remove the image

Answer (score 0):

Thinking something along the lines of:

```
.secondary, .checkout-button, .button.checkout, .button.alt {
background-color: #36ae33;
}

.button, button, input[type='submit'], input[type='reset'], input[type='button']
{
font-size: 3.48em;
  text-shadow:
    -2px -2px 0 #000,
    2px -2px 0 #000,
    -2px 2px 0 #000,
    2px 2px 0 #000;  
line-height: 1.7em;
min-height: 1.7em;
font-weight: normal;
white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Shadows not quite perfect, also think you may need a :nthchild (1) so the 'write a review' text isn't also affected.